# Ruby on Rails: Length of Video as a Paperclip Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, attachment, paperclip

I created a rails class with a video attachment, and i want to know how to get the length of a video that is uploaded to my application. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ffmpeg` and the `RVideo` gem, which is a thin Ruby wrapper around it. There's a lot of forks of the `RVideo` project, personally I use `http://github.com/greatseth/rvideo` because it supports capturing frames from video and saving them as images. When it's all set up, you can do this:

```
# For Paperclip 2
video_attributes = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => self.upload.to_file.path, :ffmpeg_binary => "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg" )
video_attributes.duration # duration in milliseconds

# For Paperclip 3
video_attributes = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => self.upload.queued_for_write[:original].path)
video_attributes.duration # duration in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 6):

I didn't get Rvideo working on fully, the gem hasn't been updated in four years. However, this works:

```
  before_post_process :get_video_duration

  def get_video_duration
    result = `ffmpeg -i #{self.video.to_file.path} 2>&1`
    r = result.match("Duration: ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).([0-9]+)")
    if r
      self.duration = r[1].to_i*3600+r[2].to_i*60+r[3].to_i
    end
  end
```

Comment: This works but you may need to use staged_path for the video if you haven't stored yet: `ffmpeg -i #{self.video.staged_path} 2>&1`, that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this recently, and this was my approach:

```
before_post_process do
  file = data.queued_for_write[:original].path
  self.duration = Paperclip.run("ffprobe", '-i %s -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"' % file).to_f
end
```

`ffprobe` is installed by ffmpeg, so if you have that installed you're probably good to go.